# How can i move my jquery modal to here and there

Tags: jquery

i create a modal , which i cannot move, it showing somewhere i specify the position.

I want to move the dialog modal.

is there any parameter for that.

Comment: Which modal plugin, if any, are you using?

Comment: That's kind of why I like to write my own stuff instead of using other people's plug ins. If you write it, you know what everything does, and you control the entire process.

Comment: @Alex - If you write it, you have to write it. The trick is to use plugins and software with good documentation, well-defined APIs, and have an active community supporting it. It's, typically, far more time-consuming to write your own.

Comment: @JasCav that is true, until you need to customize it to the point where you have to understand and rewrite practically every single line of code. I know both sides from experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but I'm assuming you are talking about the [jQuery UI Dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

If that is the case, you only need to set the "draggable" option (found in the options within the documentation). An example is like this:

```
$('div#dialog-example').dialog({
  modal: true,
  draggable: true
});
```

Something is confusing is that, by default, draggable is set to true, so you must be unsetting it. (Assuming I understand your question...it's a bit of a confusing question.)

Comment: am using jquery-ui ..i think its unsetting there..i have to check.. i was looking for this parameter mainly 'draggable'. i try to override it by giving on call like yu give..but its not.. may be style also playing with jquery-ui class.

Comment: when i show modal the layer beneath that , i make a faded layer by which the under layer is inactive.

Comment: if i make the modal draggable , still can i make the beneath layer inactive,,,only after lcosing dialog the underlying layer shud be active